# Jquery bootstrap select2 plugin issue with validate plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

In my bootstrap project I'm trying to use the plugin select2 but I realized that
if you use this plugin are no longer able to validate select fields in my form with validate plugin.
I would avoid using the commercial plugin bootstrap validator..

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <form id="test_form" action="?">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Foo</label>
                 <select class="form-control" id="foo" name="foo">
                     <option value=""></option>
                     <option value="1">1</option>
                     <option value="2">2</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Bar</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="bar" name="bar">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">VALIDATE</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
/* select 2 plugin */
$('select#foo').select2();

/* Validation */
$("#test_form").validate({
    rules:
    {
        foo: { required: true },
        bar: { required: true }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(element).addClass('err');
    },
    success: function (label, element) {
        $(element).removeClass('err');
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert("validation ok");
    }
});
```

In your opinion how could I fix this problem? Thanks

[MY DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g86nd4L7/2/)

Comment: For best practices, you should only be adding/removing the classes with `highlight` and `unhighlight`, NOT with `errorPlacement` and `success`... that's not their intended purpose.

Comment: @Sparky - I apologize for the duplicate, I had not found your answer, which is what I wanted..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. Here is what worked for me

```
/* select 2 plugin */
$('select#foo').select2();

/* Validation */
    $("#test_form").validate({
        ignore: 'input[type=hidden]',
        rules:
        {
            foo: { required: true },
            bar: { required: true }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $(element).parent().addClass('has-error');
        },
        success: function (label, element) {
            $(element).parent().removeClass('has-error');
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert("validation ok");
        }
    });
```

I added a "ignore: 'input[type=hidden]'," option because the Select2 script adds a hidden option to the original input and the Jquery Validator seems to ignore it. Then i changed the error class from "err" on the element to "has-error" on the parent element (the div with form-group class)

Comment: `ignore: 'input[type=hidden]'` means to ignore only `input type="hidden"` elements instead of the default to ignore all hidden elements.  You could specify to ignore _nothing_ hidden by using `ignore: []` and that would work too.  Otherwise, you could specify to ignore everything _except_ the hidden `select` element.

Comment: i'm not a pro developer.. i only know it worked :D thanks for your explanation ;)